# Merging Two of my Stack Overflow accounts

Tags: discussion, merge-accounts

I have two accounts in Stack Overflow. Can anyway to merge my two account into single. If not that feature implemented in Stack Overflow means when expect that feature in future?

Comment: Questions about the operation of [so] belong on [meta]

Comment: Duplicate! Its almost ironic.